# How to use jQuery instead of Prototype in a Rails 3 application?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to use jQuery instead of Prototype in my Rails 3 application.

What is the "official" Rails 3 way to do this?

Comment: @DJTripleThreat I agree with you. I was the first one to post an answer but have since removed it so as to give the credit to someone with an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First you need to install the gem, by adding this line to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 0.2.6'
```

(and run `bundle install`)
Then you need to go to the public/javascript folder and you need to replace the rails.js file by the one from: http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs.

The proper way of doing this is to do:

```
rails generate jquery:install
```

or if you want to include jQuery UI:

```
rails generate jquery:install --ui
```

*From the Github page:*

> This will remove the Prototype.js
>   library from Rails, add latest jQuery
>   library and fetch the adapter. Be sure
>   to choose to overwrite the "rails.js"
>   file.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely easy.

First, get `rails.js` from from the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs). That page also has a good set of instructions.

Then, put `rails.js` and jQuery itself in the `public/javascripts` directory.  You can clear out all other files from that directory.

Finally, in `application.rb`, add the following:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
```

This assumes that your `jQuery` file is named `jquery.js`. That line tells Rails to automatically load `jquery.js` and `rails.js` whenever `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` is encountered.

That's it! Rails 3 automatically generates attributes on the elements jQuery needs to add events to, and jQuery reads those attributes and adds the necessary events.