# Couldn't find "Object" with ID = ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Every time i delete or destroy a Product it aways give me this error in my console:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with ID=4):
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

and on the page it gives:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#show

Couldn't find Product with ID=4
```

In my Products Controller i just have the regular scaffold:

```
def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
    end
  end

def destroy
    @product = current_user.products.find(params[:id]) #current user deletes own
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(products_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

I am using Rails Jquery UJS and rails-jquery and have the `csrf_meta_tag`in my app layout. What i have noticed is when i click the destroy link and it pops up the window and says "Are you Sure", i click the OK button and it flickers TWICE for some strange reason, it never did this until i installed Jquery. How do i fix this?

**EDIT - ANSWER:**

Reinstall rails jquery-ujs > https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

You have to keep both files `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.js`. I deleted the jquery.min.js because i thought it was a minimized version but apparently not, here are all of my files from jquery-ujs:

```
   jquery.js
   jquery.min.js
   jquery_ujs.js
   rails.js # i had to install this manually from the link (or zip file)
   jquery-ui # i wanted the user interface too
```

Comment: Can you post the model code?  If it is large you can put a link to a gist on Github.  It would be good to also see application.js.

Comment: Its done, my application.js is empty, i haven't used it yet.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to 3.1 rc from an existing application? If so, I would make sure that you've uninstalled all the old prototype.js stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the `rails.js` file in `javascripts`?  When you move from prototype to jquery, the standard restful `DELETE` doesn't work properly anymore.  rails.js fixes that so it works normally again.  You can refer to Josh Huckabee's article here: http://joshhuckabee.com/jquery-rails-3.  Hopefully that helps.

PS: Also make sure you include `rails.js` in your layout.  Something like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.4.min', 'jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min', 'rails', 'application' %>
```

Comment: I just downloaded the new rails.js and still no luck. I have all of my stylesheets and javasheets enabled ( <%= javascript_include_tag :all, :cache => true, :recursive => true %>) but still no good even it is detected correctly. I think it has something to with it redirecting to the products/id when i just deleted the product, how would i change this?

Comment: If it is truly redirecting you can find out by using `ruby-debug` or you can setup a log statement like this: `logger.debug(caller)` in the `destroy` method, and wherever else you think it is going. If it is being redirected you should be able to see that, and from whence it is called.

Comment: Also, did you remove prototype when you installed jquery?  Did you follow these same steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053280/how-to-use-jquery-instead-of-prototype-in-a-rails-3-application

Comment: Yes i removed prototype and i know jquery is working correctly because i was having issue with getting my jquery-autocomplete to work. I figured out the issue, its sending a GET instead of DELETE, can this be changed?

Comment: Yes, I have also run into that issue, due to not having jquery installed properly.  Can you render the view in question and post the HTML for the delete link?  I'm sure we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Alright i found the problem. I reinstalled jquery rails and i was missing the jquery.min.js even though i had jquery.js. I thought these 2 files were the same thing just one was minimized so i deleted the jquery.min.js. Looks like i have to keep both of them. Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, but you are correct in that you should only need one or the other of those files.  *.min is as you said, a compressed version of the other file.  Glad it is working.

Comment: Its strange, it works with the jquery.min.js only but it wont work with the jquery.js. Looks like i will just be using the jquery.min.js hopefully from this point on, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you are trying to find a `product` with `id` 4 in your `show` action. There are two issues there. The first is that unless your product's id really is 4, you are probably getting `nil` from `params[:id]`. The other problem is that you are in your `show` action and not your `delete` action. This implies that either your routing is wrong or that the http verb is being changed from a `DELETE` to a `GET`.

The flickering twice maybe a related symptom, but some how you aren't sending a `DELETE` and the `params` hash is not being passed.

Comment: I delete it when i am in my products/index just like a regular scaffold where it says "Show,Edit,Destroy". In my database it says its the correct product too, i believe the problem it is redirecting to the wrong location when it should stay at the index page.