# Rails 3: Can JQuery Replace All of the Prototype Functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm still new to web programming and Rails in general. From what I understand, Prototype and JQuery are both Javascript frameworks to achieve similar goals. I love JQuery, and I want to use it! From what I understand, Prototype is included with Rails. My question is:

1. Can JQuery replace all the functionalities (such as (and most importantly to me) `link_to :remote`)) provided by Prototype?

I am using Rails 3.

(PS - I would not mind keeping them both (although I don't really have a use for Prototype if JQuery can handle its functions), but I am having a lot of problems with Prototype interfering with JQuery. E.g. If I 'src' the JQuery file first, Prototype doesn't work (for my `link_to :remote`. But if I 'src' Prototype first, JQuery doesn't work at all!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery instead of Prototype in a Rails 3 application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053280/how-to-use-jquery-instead-of-prototype-in-a-rails-3-application)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've revised my question to reflect only my second part of the question.

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate.  The link question is about if it is possible, this question is about functionality differences between jQuery and prototype with regard to rails.

Comment: Google for "jQuery.noConflict" in order to solve your problem of making jQuery coexist with prototype.

Comment: Zabba, he wants to get rid of that lousy prototype and **replace** it with jQuery.

Comment: Then the answer is "yes", `link_to :remote` works fine. When someone asks if it can "replace" something, I think the assumption is that the framework using its functionality would still continue to function. It's a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to Rails 3.1, which has JQuery replacing Prototype by default, I can say yes... JQuery works with all the Prototype features, such as `:remote => true` that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs